# Placing input field value inside data annotation parameter for another form field asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a set of radio buttons and a text field. I want to make the text field required if one of the two radio buttons are selected. I made a custom validation class using data annotations. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the value of the radio buttons to the data annotations as a parameter. I can't seem to use the "radioButton" inside it gives be an error becuase its not static. But I cant just make it static or it breaks other code that I can't change.
Model

```
public string radioButton
        {
            get => This.ArchiveFileOptions;
            set => SetProperty(This.ArchiveFileOptions, value, () =>
            {
                This.ArchiveFileOptions = value;
                ObjectState = ObjectState != ObjectStateEnum.Added ? ObjectStateEnum.Modified : ObjectStateEnum.Added;
            });
        }


        [IfRadioSelectedTextRequired(text: "Single Pdfs", radioValue: {{RADIO BUTTON VALUE HERE}})]
        public string textField
        {
            get => This.PdfIndexingRequirements;
            set => SetProperty(This.PdfIndexingRequirements, value, () => { This.PdfIndexingRequirements = value; ObjectState = ObjectState != ObjectStateEnum.Added ? ObjectStateEnum.Modified : ObjectStateEnum.Added; });
        }
```

custom class

```
public class IfRadioSelectedTextRequired : ValidationAttribute
    {

        private readonly string _text;
        private readonly string _radioValue;
        public IfRadioSelectedTextRequired(string text, string radioValue)
        {

            _text = text;
            _radioValue = radioValue;
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var fieldValue = value as string;

            if (_radioValue != null)
            {
                if (_radioValue == _text)
                {

                    if (fieldValue == null)
                    {
                        //error
                        return new ValidationResult($"This field is required");
                    }
                    if (fieldValue == "")
                    {
                        //error
                        return new ValidationResult($"This field is required");
                    }
                    if (fieldValue != null)
                    {
                        //success
                        return ValidationResult.Success;
                    }
                }
                if (_radioValue != _text)
                {
                    //success
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }


            //success
            return ValidationResult.Success;


        }

    }
```

I've tried adding the field name inside the data annotation. I was wondering if there is a way to pull it inside the class.